# How to a reference the shared source without depending on a project

Tags: scala, sbt, scala.js

Say I have a project defined as follows:

```
val commonSettings = Seq(
    name := "project1",
    version := "1.0",
    scalaVersion := "2.12.8",
    unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile +=
        baseDirectory.value / ".." / "shared" / "src" / "main" / "scala"
)

val client = project.in(file("client"))
    .settings(commonSettings: _*)

val server = project.in(file("server"))
    .settings(commonSettings: _*)
```

And I have a second project that uses a REST api to communicate with this server. Thus the second project uses code defined in the shared source of the first. The second project cannot depend on the entire project1 as there are incompatibilities between the sbt versions for the two projects.

What do I need to add to my build.sbt and/or change in the first project in order for the second project to reference the shared source?

Comment: What about creating a third project which only has the shared sources, publish it as a library, and make both _(project1 & project2)_ add it as a dependency.

Comment: The problem with trying to create a separate project is that once I remove the unmanagedSourceDirectories declaration from common settings the optimizing compilation of the js files will fail with linking errors - as it can no longer find any of the referred classes in share.

Comment: But you would refer to them as a library. That should work. Or I am misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0):

If project1 and project 2 are finally going to run independently it would be better if you write REST APIs to communicate in between them.
You can write an API in project2 and hit it from project1 to run the shared code of project2.

Otherwise, why not just replicate shared code from project2 to project1 ?

Answer (score -1):

You can try [jitpack](https://jitpack.io/), add below lines in your `build.sbt` to enable jitpack resolver and add appropriate dependencies

```
    resolvers += "jitpack" at "https://jitpack.io"

    // you can also use specific sha or tag instead of master-SNAPSHOT
    libraryDependencies       += "org.xyz" %% "project" % "master-SNAPSHOT"
```